Use column headers in drop-down filter in the free version of Google Looker
I have a table that I'm displaying in a Looker dashboard. Ideally, I want two drop-down filters for this table. One to filter on the left-most column, "Name" (as shown below), and then a filter for the column headers. Basically, I want to be able to filter the table down to a 1:1 format.
Table below, where Person A is the "Name" column, and Person B should represent the column headers -

Ideally, I want to be able to filter down the table to look something like this (where it's one name in the second column, "Banquet Beer" in this example, and one in the "Name" column, Jack Black in the photo):

